# boto3 remove Decimal() notation from dynamodb query results - python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

So I'm working with `boto3`, trying to retrieve some data from a `dynamoDB` table, and every number that is returned to me is using this Decimal(..) notation, like instead of getting

```
{
 "itemId" : 123
}
I get
{
 "itemId": Decimal(123)
}
```

Is there a way to remove this without having to write a `regExp` for it?

I was doing it manually with a for, for example using `int(itemId)` and it worked for some items but these are very big and complex objects that don't always have the same structure and key names, so I can't do everything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I create a DecimalEncoder class and use it to parse my data when needed. Here is an example:

```
import boto3
import json
import decimal

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('MyTable')
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
    Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
    """
    def default(self, o):  # pylint: disable=E0202
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if abs(o) % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)


def getitem():
    ddbresponse = table.get_item(
        Key={'pk': 'a', 'sk': 'b'},
        ConsistentRead=True
    )
    return json.dumps(ddbresponse['Item'], cls=DecimalEncoder) if 'Item' in ddbresponse else ddbresponse

print(getitem())
```

DynamoDB has no idea what data type a number actually is, which causes python to represent it as a Decimal.

Comment: This is pretty useful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use json_util from `dynamodb-json`. It's a util that would convert JSON to DynamoDB format for storing and also converts from dynamoDB format to regular JSON, with properly converting numbers to their respective types.
Install it with pip:

```
pip install dynamodb-json
```

Import it:

```
from dynamodb_json import json_util
```

Then you use it the same way you would use `json.loads`, just use `json_util.loads(data)`